# C# Create Instance of Generic class which inheritance from base

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create instance of class Bar but I'm receiving an error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type `ConsoleApplication1.Bar` to
>   `ConsoleApplication1.BaseFoo<ConsoleApplication1.baseOutput,
>   ConsoleApplication1.baseInput>`"

Any idea what I'm missing or what I'm doing wrong? Any advice will be nice.

```
public class baseOutput
{
    public string output;
}

public class baseInput
{
    public string input;
}

public class ExtendOutput : baseOutput
{
    public long id;
}

public class ExtendInput : baseInput
{
    public long id;
}

public class BaseFoo<baseOutput, baseInput>
{
    protected virtual void DoSmth()
    {

    }
}

public class Bar : BaseFoo<ExtendOutput, ExtendInput>
{
    protected override void DoSmth()
    {
        base.DoSmth();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void Show()
    {

    }

    private BaseFoo<baseOutput, baseInput> CreateInstance()
    {
        return new Bar(); // Error right here
    }
}
```

Comment: Just because `A : B` and `C : D`, does not mean that `A<C> : B<D>`. Look up covariance in C# - it will allow you to do what you're attempting, with a few restrictions.

Comment: Please stick to the C# coding convention; "public class BaseFoo<baseOutput, baseInput>" is misleading since you have classes with same names (baseOutput and baseInput).

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you an example of why you're prevented from doing that.

Imagine instead, your classes were written like this:

```
public class BaseFoo<TOutput, TInput>
    where TOutput : BaseOutput
{
    public TOutput Something { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : BaseFoo<ExtendOutput, ExtendInput>
{

}

public class BaseInput { }
public class BaseOutput { }
public class ExtendOutput : BaseOutput { }
public class SomethingElse : BaseOutput { }
```

Now, you have this method:

```
private BaseFoo<BaseOutput, BaseInput> CreateInstance()
{
    //At this point, Something will be of type ExtendOutput.
    return new Bar();
}
```

So, we call it like this:

```
var myBar = CreateInstance();
```

Now, `mybar.Something` is of type *BaseOutput*. That's fine, though, because `ExtendOutput : BaseOutput`, right? Not quite.

What happens when we do this:

```
myBar.Something = new SomethingElse();
```

That's valid, because `Something` expects a `BaseOutput`, and `SomethingElse` is a `BaseOutput`. *However*, the object is actually a *Bar*, which explicitly says it should be an `ExtendOutput`.

The problem is clearer if we attempt to cast it back:

```
var myBaseFoo = CreateInstance();
myBaseFoo.Something = new SomethingElse();
Bar myBar = (Bar)myBaseFoo;
myBar.Something; // Here, we're told it's going to be an `ExtendOutput`, 
                 // but we get a `SomethingElse`?
```

That's clearly wrong. And *that's* why you're prevented from doing what you're trying to do. You can have this behavior with [covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/mt654055.aspx).

Covariance makes it illegal to pass in a `TOutput`. So, this line

```
public TOutput Something { get; set; }
```

Would be invalid. We would only be allowed to expose the getter:

```
public TOutput Something { get; }
```

Which alleviates the above problem

Answer (score 1):

`Bar` is `BaseFoo<ExtendOutput, ExtendInput>`, and `CreateInstance()` requires `BaseFoo<baseOutput, baseInput>` to be returned, so it can't return `Bar` which is `BaseFoo<ExtendOutput, ExtendInput>`.

Regardless `ExtendOutput` inherits `baseOutput`, when you inherit a generic class the inheritance is [invariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx).

Consider using interfaces with [in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) and [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) generic modifiers:

```
public class baseOutput
{
    public string output;
}

public class baseInput
{
    public string input;
}

public class ExtendOutput : baseOutput
{
    public long id;
}

public class ExtendInput : baseInput
{
    public long id;
}

public interface IBaseFoo<out T1, out T2>
{
    public void DoSmth();
}

public class Bar : IBaseFoo<ExtendOutput, ExtendInput>
{
    public void DoSmth()
    {

    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void Show()
    {

    }

    private IBaseFoo<baseOutput, baseInput> CreateInstance()
    {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```